# Use Regex toPrecision

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a question. , example like this:

result text

```
2.27e-9
```

i want text

```
2.27
```

or

```
2.28
```

how to remove `e-9` use regex or other..

Thanks for everybody who can help me :D

Comment: Why tag the question as `PHP` when you need a `JS` solution ? Removed the `PHP` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this fiddle:

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PvU7n/6/)

And here goes the code:

```
var num = 3.14e-14 ;
var patt1 = /\d+\.\d+/;
var result = num.toString().match(patt1);
alert(result);
```